# Colored blocks on boot

Tags: hard-drive, boot

When my laptop tries to boot right after POST I see colored blocks with flashing symbols in them. I am able to boot from windows PE cd. Tried fixboot and fixmbr with no success. I have also tried replacing boot files (ntldr, io.sys etc..) and removing video card drivers from windows\system32\drivers.  The drive is seagate 2.5 ATA 160GB and has one NTFS partition on it. I have already fixed this issue by reformating the drive and reinstalling everything but after couple of weeks I get the same issue again. The diagnostics software shows no bad sectors on it and virus scan didn't find anything. Does anybody have an idea what this might be?

UPDATE: tried defragmenting the hard drive just in case, but still no luck

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a hard drive issue, if it's come back after a reformat. What software did you use to scan for bad sectors? Try either HDTune (Windows) or BadBlocks (Linux), and check if it gives the same results.

Comment: Tried HDTune but both health status and error scan show that everything is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Test your video subsystem and main system RAM.  Used to see this a lot when the video RAM went bad.  The reason you need to test both is that the lower end video cards use system RAM instead of having much dedicated RAM.